# Access iOS Apps List in iTunes via Win32 COM?

Tags: python, iphone, ios, itunes, itunes-sdk

I've been using Python to script Win32 iTunes, and it's been rocky but doable.  However, I wanted to move beyond just media (songs, etc.) to analyze what apps were on my devices.  Can anyone recommend how to use the iTunes Win32 COM interface to, say, get a list of apps that are currently on the phone?

I thought the app list might be exposed as a playlist, with each app as an IITFileOrCDTrack, but that doesn't seem to be the case.  When I look at my phone as a source, it just lists media playlists (books, movies, etc.)

Or, if you can suggest a different way to do this from Python, open to suggestions.  I assumed I'd have to use iTunes as my phone is not jailbroken and I don't know any other way to see what's on the phone, but if there is another way, cool.  I don't need to add or remove, just want to see what's there.

Thanks for any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Apple does not offer any APIs to achieve this.